# Java program to output unicode chars in cmd

Tags: java, unicode, command-prompt

In the [java se 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1) specifications it is written that

> A Java compiler should use the \uxxxx notation as an output format to
>   display Unicode characters when a suitable font is not available.

But when I run the below program, the command prompt displays a `Hell?, World!` instead of \uxxxx notation.

```
import java.io.*;

class test{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Hell\u0c13, World!");
  }
}
```

As my command prompt doesn't have a suitabe font, the compiler must be printing the below output.

```
Hell\u0c13, World!
```

I'm also wondering how the java compiler will determine whether suitable font is available or not. Please help.

Comment: You misunderstood the sentence in the JLS. It says that the Java compiler itself will print characters using \uxxxx notation, not that compiled programs will do this. The **compiler** is not running your program, it's only compiling your program.

Comment: Your code != java compiler. Your code is responsible itself for the output it produces

Comment: Ok got it. I wonder where will the java compiler print these characters and what it has to do with the font? Can you please explain some details?