# unicode output java windows cmd

Tags: java, intellij-idea, unicode

I'm new to java so excuse me if this is commong knowldge but I have searched hard and couldn't find anything helpful, relevant or understandable(Which is odd considering I'm a C developer!).
My question is "How can I make java print a Unicode string in the windows shell ?". For simplicity say I have the hello world code in another language(ex: "سلام") and I want to display it in the shell (actually i want to get Unicode too, but first I have to figure this one out).
This works perfectly in Intellij IDEA without any extra lines of code!

```
System.out.println("سلام");
```

but doesn't work in shell.

I'm seriously disappointed, I migrated from C just to get a better deal with Unicode!

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627898/java-program-to-output-unicode-chars-in-cmd

Comment: unfortunately Doesn't work!

Comment: For me it worked on Intellij IDEA Run window but not on Windows CMD. Which one are you using?

Comment: Windows CMD does not use Unicode, but a Microsoft codepage.
Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386335/printing-out-unicode-from-java-code-issue-in-windows-console

Comment: What is the language of the text in your call to println() - is it Persian? Also, what operating system/version are you using?

Comment: Its persian and Im running it on Windows 10. Your solution worked except for the backwards rendering. Thanks alot.

Comment: @A.Rahimi I have updated my answer so that **"سلام"** is rendered correctly in the **Command Prompt** window, but the cost is that it no longer renders correctly when run in Intellij IDEA. (So it's still not a proper solution.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used Intellij IDEA/Java 1.8 on Windows 10 and tried a bunch of things in a somewhat disorganized manner, but have it almost working. First, here's the code:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Java901App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.out.println("Hello world!");
        //System.out.println("سلام");
        try{
            PrintStream outStream = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
            outStream.println("Hello world!");
            outStream.println("سلام");
        } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            System.out.println("Caught exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

- Note that the encoding for the PrintStream is set to UTF-8. See the selected answer for this post: [Chinese Characters Displayed as Questions Marks in Mac Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488628/chinese-characters-displayed-as-questions-marks-in-mac-terminal/15516722#15516722)
- <strike>I added **Arabic Script Supplemental Fonts** to Windows based on this article from Microsoft: [Why does some text display with square boxes in some apps on Windows 10?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3083806/why-does-some-text-display-with-square-boxes-in-some-apps-on-windows-1) I'm not sure whether this was essential, but it definitely did no harm.</strike> I uninstalled **Arabic Script Supplemental Fonts** and nothing changed so this step was not necessary.
- Before running the app from the console I called **chcp 65001**. That was definitely essential even though the **PrintStream** was defined to use UTF-8, as shown in the screen shot below.
- I tried setting different fonts for the **Command Prompt** window by clicking the icon in the top left of the window, selecting Defaults form the dropdown menu and then clicking the **Fonts** tab. Some worked (e.g. Consolas) and some didn't (e.g. MS Gothic). Note this comment from a SuperUser post: [In order for chcp 65001 to work, you must be using a TrueType font in the command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/237081/whats-the-code-page-of-utf-8).
- Here's some sample output:
  [image: RenderingUTF8]
- So it is working except that the characters in the text you provided are being rendered in reverse order. Does anyone know how to fix that, presumably by somehow specifying in the Java source that the text is for a right-to-left language?

---

**Update:**

I amended the code so that the Persian text is rendered correctly in the Command Prompt window, though a side effect is that it no longer renders correctly when the code is run within the IDE. Here's the revised code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        StringBuilder persianHello = new StringBuilder("سلام");
        PrintStream outStream = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
        outStream.println("Hello world!");
        outStream.println(persianHello); // Renders backwards in console, but correctly in the IDE.
        byte directionality = Character.getDirectionality(persianHello.charAt(0));
        if (directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT_ARABIC) {
            outStream.println("Reversed string:" + persianHello.reverse()); // Renders correctly in console, but backwards in the IDE...
        }
    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        System.out.println("Caught exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And here's the **Command Prompt** output using that code:

[image: ReversedPersian]

This fix is a hack; what's really needed is code that will behave correctly regardless of whether it is run from the IDE or the **Command Prompt**.